# How to fix FATAL EXCEPTION: main android.content.res.Resources$NotFoundException

Tags: android, android-appcompat, android-resources

When I try to run my app on Android 4.1 it brings up an error however it works on anything above API level 21.

```
FATAL EXCEPTION: main
android.content.res.Resources$NotFoundException: Resource ID #0x7f020059
at android.content.res.Resources.getValue(Resources.java:1013)
at android.support.v7.widget.AppCompatDrawableManager.loadDrawableFromDelegates(AppCompatDrawableManager.java:327)
at android.support.v7.widget.AppCompatDrawableManager.getDrawable(AppCompatDrawableManager.java:192)
at android.support.v7.widget.AppCompatDrawableManager.getDrawable(AppCompatDrawableManager.java:185)
at android.support.v7.content.res.AppCompatResources.getDrawable(AppCompatResources.java:100)
at android.support.v7.view.menu.MenuItemImpl.getIcon(MenuItemImpl.java:421)
at android.support.design.internal.NavigationMenuItemView.initialize(NavigationMenuItemView.java:113)
at android.support.design.internal.NavigationMenuPresenter$NavigationMenuAdapter.onBindViewHolder(NavigationMenuPresenter.java:415)
at android.support.design.internal.NavigationMenuPresenter$NavigationMenuAdapter.onBindViewHolder(NavigationMenuPresenter.java:338)
at android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView$Adapter.onBindViewHolder(RecyclerView.java:5825)
at android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView$Adapter.bindViewHolder(RecyclerView.java:5858)
at android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView$Recycler.getViewForPosition(RecyclerView.java:5094)
at android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView$Recycler.getViewForPosition(RecyclerView.java:4970)
at android.support.v7.widget.LinearLayoutManager$LayoutState.next(LinearLayoutManager.java:2029)
at android.support.v7.widget.LinearLayoutManager.layoutChunk(LinearLayoutManager.java:1414)
at android.support.v7.widget.LinearLayoutManager.fill(LinearLayoutManager.java:1377)
at android.support.v7.widget.LinearLayoutManager.onLayoutChildren(LinearLayoutManager.java:578)
at android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView.dispatchLayoutStep2(RecyclerView.java:3315)
at android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView.dispatchLayout(RecyclerView.java:3124)
at android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView.onLayout(RecyclerView.java:3568)
at android.view.View.layout(View.java:13754)
at android.view.ViewGroup.layout(ViewGroup.java:4364)
at android.widget.FrameLayout.onLayout(FrameLayout.java:448)
at android.view.View.layout(View.java:13754)
at android.view.ViewGroup.layout(ViewGroup.java:4364)
at android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout.onLayout(DrawerLayout.java:1221)
at android.view.View.layout(View.java:13754)
at android.view.ViewGroup.layout(ViewGroup.java:4364)
at android.widget.FrameLayout.onLayout(FrameLayout.java:448)
at android.view.View.layout(View.java:13754)
at android.view.ViewGroup.layout(ViewGroup.java:4364)
at android.widget.LinearLayout.setChildFrame(LinearLayout.java:1649)
at android.widget.LinearLayout.layoutVertical(LinearLayout.java:1507)
at android.widget.LinearLayout.onLayout(LinearLayout.java:1420)
at android.view.View.layout(View.java:13754)
at android.view.ViewGroup.layout(ViewGroup.java:4364)
at android.widget.FrameLayout.onLayout(FrameLayout.java:448)
at android.view.View.layout(View.java:13754)
at android.view.ViewGroup.layout(ViewGroup.java:4364)
at android.widget.LinearLayout.setChildFrame(LinearLayout.java:1649)
at android.widget.LinearLayout.layoutVertical(LinearLayout.java:1507)
at android.widget.LinearLayout.onLayout(LinearLayout.java:1420)
at android.view.View.layout(View.java:13754)
at android.view.ViewGroup.layout(ViewGroup.java:4364)
at android.widget.FrameLayout.onLayout(FrameLayout.java:448)
at android.view.View.layout(View.java:13754)
at android.view.ViewGroup.layout(ViewGroup.java:4364)
at android.view.ViewRootImpl.performLayout(ViewRootImpl.java:1868)
at android.view.ViewRootImpl.performTraversals(ViewRootImpl.java:1689)
at android.view.ViewRootImpl.doTraversal(ViewRootImpl.java:1000)
at android.view.ViewRootImpl$TraversalRunnable.run(ViewRootImpl.java:4214)
at android.view.Choreographer$CallbackRecord.run(Choreographer.java:725)
at android.view.Choreographer.doCallbacks(Choreographer.java:555)
at android.view.Choreographer.doFrame(Choreographer.java:525)
at android.view.C
```

I've followed a tutorial and changed my toolbar so that I could change the background colors on the text but it just does not simply work on anything below API 21. Any ideas on how to fix it? It's driving me crazy.

These are the files I mainly changed when changing the colour so I think the problem is within these.

styles.xml

```
<resources>

    <!-- Base application theme. -->
    <style name="AppTheme" parent="AppTheme.Base" >
    <!-- Base application theme.
         Defining this lets values-v21/styles.xml reuse it with changes. -->
    </style>
    <style name="AppTheme.NoActionBar">
        <item name="windowActionBar">false</item>
        <item name="windowNoTitle">true</item>
    </style>
    <style name="AppTheme.Base" parent="Theme.AppCompat.NoActionBar">
        <!-- colorPrimary is used, for instance, for the default ActionBar
             (but not Toolbar) background.
              We specify the same color for the toolbar background in
              toolbar.xml.. -->
        <item name="colorPrimary">@color/colorPrimary</item>

        <!-- colorPrimaryDark is used for the status bar (with the
             battery, clock, etc). -->
        <item name="colorPrimaryDark">@color/colorPrimaryDark</item>

        <!-- colorAccent is used as the default value for
             colorControlActivated which is used to tint widgets. -->
        <item name="colorAccent">@color/colorAccent</item>
    </style>

    <style name="AppTheme.AppBarOverlay" parent="ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Dark.ActionBar" />
    <style name="AppTheme.PopupOverlay" parent="ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Light" />
    <style name="GalaxyZooThemeToolbarDarkOverflow" parent="Theme.AppCompat.NoActionBar">
        <!-- android:textColorPrimary is the  color of the title text
             in the Toolbar, in the Theme.AppCompat theme:  -->
        <item name="android:textColorPrimary">#4e4e4e</item>

        <!-- android:textColorPrimaryInverse is the  color of the title
             text in the Toolbar, in the Theme.AppCompat.Light theme:  -->
        <!-- <item name="android:textColorPrimaryInverse">@color/abc_primary_text_material_light</item> -->

        <!-- android:actionMenuTextColor is the color of the text of
              action (menu) items in the Toolbar, at least in the
              Theme.AppCompat theme.
              For some reason, they already get the textColorPrimary
              when running on API 21, but not on older versions of
              Android, so this is only necessary to support older
              Android versions.-->
        <item name="actionMenuTextColor">@color/abc_primary_text_material_light</item>
        <!-- android:textColorSecondary is the color of the menu
             overflow icon (three vertical dots) -->
        <item name="android:textColorSecondary">@color/abc_secondary_text_material_light</item>

        <!-- This would set the toolbar's background color,
              but setting this also changes the popup menu's background,
              even if we define popupTheme for our <Toolbar> -->
        <!-- <item name="android:background">@color/color_primary</item> -->
    </style>

</resources>
```

app_bar_main.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
    tools:context="com.dawsn.fitigniterapp.MainActivity">

    <android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme.AppBarOverlay">

        <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
            xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
            xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
            android:id="@+id/toolbar"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
            android:background="@color/colorPrimary"
            app:theme="@style/GalaxyZooThemeToolbarDarkOverflow"
            app:popupTheme="@style/AppTheme.PopupOverlay" />

    </android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout>

    <include layout="@layout/content_main"/>

</android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout>
```

nav_header_main.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="@dimen/nav_header_height"
    android:background="@drawable/side_nav_bar"
    android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    android:theme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Dark"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:gravity="bottom">

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:paddingTop="@dimen/nav_header_vertical_spacing"
        android:text="You are not logged in"
        android:textAppearance="@style/TextAppearance.AppCompat.Body1"
        android:id="@+id/txtUserName"
        android:textColor="@color/navheadertext" />

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:text="Please log into see your details"
        android:id="@+id/txtNotLogged"
        android:textColor="@android:color/black" />

</LinearLayout>
```

styles.xml (v21)

```
<resources>
    <style name="AppTheme.NoActionBar" >
        <item name="windowActionBar">false</item>
        <item name="windowNoTitle">true</item>
        <item name="android:windowDrawsSystemBarBackgrounds">true</item>
        <item name="android:statusBarColor">@android:color/transparent</item>
    </style>
</resources>
```

AndroidManifest.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.dawsn.fitigniterapp" >
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />

    <application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:supportsRtl="true"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme" >

        <meta-datas
            android:name="com.google.android.gms.version"
            android:value="@integer/google_play_services_version" />

        <activity
            android:name="com.dawsn.fitigniterapp.MainActivity"
            android:label="@string/app_name"
            android:theme="@style/AppTheme.NoActionBar" >
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>

        <activity
            android:name="com.google.android.gms.ads.AdActivity"
            android:configChanges="keyboard|keyboardHidden|orientation|screenLayout|uiMode|screenSize|smallestScreenSize"
            android:theme="@android:style/Theme.Translucent" />
    </application>

</manifest>
```

Comment: Sounds like you need to edit `values-v21`

Comment: Edited it with my v21 styles file

Comment: If you (temporarily) remove that v21 values folder, what happens?

Comment: Same error. I've tried cleaning it too.

Comment: `AppTheme.NoActionBar`. It has no parent. I think that's the problem

Comment: Don't think `AppTheme.noActionbar` needs a parent. It had no parent on the default template

Comment: Well, you use `Theme.AppCompat.NoActionBar`, which is the correct theme for no actionbar, but you've set colors inside of it (I assume for when you set the Toolbar within the Java code). So then is the other `AppTheme.NoActionBar` really necessary? In your manifest, what if you set `android:theme` to something else for that Activity? Or remove it since the `<application>` tag already provides a theme?